# Using Go Runtime in Substrate node template

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime

I am trying to run a local network using [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) and have replaced the wasm runtime with one, built from Go. Unfortunately, when I start the network I get the following error:

> Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Error calling api function: Unknown version")))

So far, I have been able to execute runtime functions (e.g. `Core_version`) using [Gossamer](https://github.com/chainsafe/gossamer), and using Rust's [wasmer](https://docs.rs/wasmer/latest/wasmer/) and [wasmtime](https://docs.rs/wasmtime/latest/wasmtime/).

I was wondering if there is some specific requirement in [sc_executor](https://docs.rs/sc-executor/latest/sc_executor/) that might affect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/executor/common/src/runtime_blob/runtime_blob.rs#L188), `min` and `max` were the same and whenever the memory wanted to `grow`, it could not, as it had already reached the maximum.